# Call angular function from puppeteer

Tags: angular, function, puppeteer

I have an Angular website and I want to use puppeteer to do some actions on it and take screenshots.
I need to call an angular function after my page loading.

If I open my page in chrome, I can call my angular function with:

```
ng.probe($$('app-home')[0]).componentInstance.myFunction()
```

But with puppeteer, if I try to do:

```
await page.evaluate("ng.probe($$('app-home')[0]).componentInstance.myFunction()")
```

I have an error saying `Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: $$ is not defined`

I tried to declare a js function in my angular component with:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.text = "function launchMyFunction() {" +
    "ng.probe($$('app-home')[0]).componentInstance.myFunction()" +
    "}"
this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
```

With Chrome dev tools console, this works fine. With puppeteer, I can call the function but I keep getting the `Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: $$ is not defined` message.

If I try to change my function, to log something for example, it works correctly, the problem seems to be ng.probe.

Is there a way to call an angular function from puppeteer?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `$$` function is undefined inside the page. The `$$` function is part of the [Console Utilities API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities). That means it is available in the console when you open your DevTools in Chrome, but it is not actually available to any function executed inside the page. To quote the docs linked above:

> **Warning:** These functions only work when you call them from the Chrome DevTools Console. They won't work if you try to call them in your scripts

---

If you look at what the function `$$` does ([docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#queryselectorall)), you can see that it's just an replacement for the `document.querySelectorAll()` function, againt quoting the docs:

> `$$(selector)` returns an array of elements that match the given CSS selector. This command is equivalent to calling [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

**Code**

So if you replace `$$` with `document.querySelectorAll()` or with `document.querySelector` in your code it should work:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-home')).componentInstance.myFunction()
});
```

Comment: How do you start the Angular/Puppeteer application? All the examples I see start the application with `ng test app` but I don't want to test it, I want to use it to generate PDFs/images at server side